# How to duplicate an Item in Object inline definition?

Tags: javascript, modularity

I'm a collaborator of a project called Duckuino, and modules are loaded with an `eval()` executing the content of another file with a `new Object()` inside, and I want to make aliases to items, to avoid repeating code twice, like that:

```
new Object({
  commands: {
    aVeryComplexCommand: function(WithParams) {
      // Complex content
    },
    anAliasForTheCommand: //something which point to 'aVeryComplexCommand'
  }
});
```

Please note that I can't put code after the `new Object()` declaration because it could be misinterpreted by the `eval()` and I don't want to modify the code which loads the module because aliases are module-specific.

Thanks by advance !

**Edit:** The answers from both Pointy and Nathan P. are working, so I'll discuss about that with my other collaborator and I'll valid the answer we used.

Comment: You cannot do that in JavaScript in an object initializer. You'd have to use a separate statement.

Comment: @Pointy: There is no workaround or weird code with a `this` statement or anything ?

Comment: see my answer; `this` is not involved with object initializers.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to use a separate statement:

```
new Object(function() {
  var obj = {
    commands: {
      aComplexCommand: { ... }
    }
  };
  obj.commands.alias = obj.commands.aComplexCommand;
  return obj;
}());
```

That's valid JavaScript, but whether that will confuse your `eval()` mechanism I can't say.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like this, using a proxy-like function :

```js
var o = new Object({
  commands: {
    aVeryComplexCommand: function(With, Params) {
      console.log('This is complex !', With, Params);
    },
    anAliasForTheCommand: function() {
      var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
      return this.aVeryComplexCommand.apply(this, args);
    }
  }
});

o.commands.anAliasForTheCommand('hello', 'world');
```

Comment: You forgot the return to be a perfect two-way proxy but it works, I'll figure out what to use with my other collaborator ^^ Thanks :D